# Automapper dictionary to object configuration

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using `AutoMapper v8.0.0`, I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` with keys that do not correspond to legal c# property names. The use case fits with the inverse of the `MapToAttribute` functionality described in [Add a MapFromAttribute for when mapping to an external type](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2506). In that issue, someone posted a gist for an extension method that implements the functionality.

In this case, how do you setup the mapper configuration when you are not mapping from one type to another, but instead mapping straight to the type as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "name with spaces", "foo" },
    { "name-with-hyphens", "foo" },
    { "nameWithDifferentCASE", "foo" },
};
class MyModel
{
    public string NameWithSpaces { get; set; }
    public string NameWithHyphens { get; set; }
    public string NameWithDifferentCase { get; set; }
}
var myModel= mapper.Map<MyModel>(dictionary);
```

All the configuration expressions are based on source and destination types.

Comment: You have to first map the keys yourself an then, once you have the property names, map to the destination.

Comment: Ok, so in these cases no configuration is leveraged when aligning maps. Thanks for the confirmation.